# Derivation of Gauss-Newton method for underdetermined inverse problems

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

I would like to derive the Gauss-Newton method for solving underdetermined inverse problems, i.e., where the parameter space is larger than the number of constraints. Although my final solution works, I do not understand how the method can be derived for such underdetermined problems:

Let $f$ be a scalar objective function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that we wish to minimize using the Gauss-Newton algorithm, i.e.,
$$f=\sum_{i=1}^m r_i^2(\underline{\alpha}),$$
where $\underline{\alpha} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector of $n$ parameters, $r_i$ describes the i-th constraint (residual) and $m$ is the number of constraints. To the best of my knowledge and according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Newton_algorithm) , the Gauss-newton algorithm can be derived directly from Newton's method, i.e.,
$$\underline{\alpha}^{\nu+1} = \underline{\alpha}^{\nu} - \underline{\underline{H}}^{-1}\underline{g},\tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
where $\underline{g}$ and $\underline{\underline{H}}$ are the gradient vector and Hessian matrix of $f$. The gradient vector in index notation is given as
$$g_j=2\sum_{i=1}^m r_i \frac{\partial r_i}{\partial \alpha_j}$$
and the Hessian is
$$H_{jk}=2\sum_{i=1}^m\left(\frac{\partial r_i}{\partial \alpha_j} \frac{\partial r_i}{\partial \alpha_k} +r_i \frac{\partial^2 r_i}{\partial \alpha_j \partial \alpha_k}\right).$$
In order to obtain the Gauss-Newton method, we ignore the second-order derivatives of the Hessian. Thus,
$$\underline{g} = 2 \underline{\underline{J}}_r^T \underline{r}$$
and
$$\underline{\underline{H}} \approx 2 \underline{\underline{J}}_r^T \underline{\underline{J}}_r,$$
where $\underline{\underline{J}}_r$ is the Jacobian of the residual vector $\underline{r}\in\mathbb{R}^m$. With this, we can now write the Gauss-Newton algorithm, i.e.,
$$\underline{\alpha}^{\nu+1} = \underline{\alpha}^{\nu} - \left (\underline{\underline{J}}_r^T \underline{\underline{J}}_r \right)^{-1} \underline{\underline{J}}_r^T \underline{r}.\tag{2}\label{eq2}$$
For the usual case with $m>n$ (overdetermined problem), this algorithm works perfectly fine for me. However, if $m<n$ (underdetermined inverse problem), $\left (\underline{\underline{J}}_r^T \underline{\underline{J}}_r \right)$ becomes singular and cannot be inverted. I realized that I can overcome this problem if I replace the left pseudoinverse of Equation \ref{eq2} by the right pseudoinverse, i.e.,
$$\underline{\alpha}^{\nu+1} = \underline{\alpha}^{\nu} - \underline{\underline{J}}_r^T\left (\underline{\underline{J}}_r \underline{\underline{J}}^T_r \right)^{-1} \underline{r}\tag{3}\label{eq3}.$$
With this modification, my algorithm works perfectly fine and converges to a solution. However, I do not understand which assumptions are necessary to derive Equation \ref{eq3}, e.g. similarly to what was done above for Equation \ref{eq2} based on Newton's method (\ref{eq1}). I assume that in my derivation, I implicitly assume $m>n$, but I do not know where.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a system of equations $$g(x) = 0$$ where $$g : \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$$ and $$n \leq m$$ so that there are at least as many unknowns as there are constraints. By Taylor's formula we have $$g(x+ \Delta x) \approx g(x) + Dg(x) \Delta x$$ where $$Dg(x) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$$ is the Jacobian of $g$ at the point $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$. We observe that $Dg(x)$ is a *wide* matrix with at least as many columns as rows. In order to derive Newton's method we seek $\Delta x \in \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $$g(x) + Dg(x) \Delta x = 0.$$ Suppose that there exists such a $\Delta x$, then there are unique
$$y \in \text{Ker}(Dg(x)), \quad z \in \text{Ran}(Dg(x)^T)$$
such that
$$\Delta x = y + z.$$
Here $\text{Ker}(A)$ denotes the kernel or null space of the linear transformation $A$ and $\text{Ran}(A)$ denotes the range or column space of the linear transformation $A$. It is clear that $y$ is irrelevant since
$$ g(x) + Dg(x)\Delta x = g(x) + Dg(x) z.$$
Now if $z \in \text{Ran}(Dg(x)^T)$, then
$$ z = Dg(x)^T p$$ for some $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
It follows that we should consider the equation
$$ g(x) + Dg(x) Dg(x)^T p  = 0$$
If we **assume** that $Dg(x)$ has full row rank, then
$$ Dg(x) Dg(x)^T \in \mathbb{R}^{n  \times n} $$
is nonsingular and our equation has a unique solution $p$. It follows Newton's method takes the form
$$ x \gets x - Dg(x)^T(Dg(x)Dg(x)^T)^{-1} g(x).$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer (and sorry for the late reply-had to refresh my linear algebra skills at first). This explanation makes sense for me. As I understand it, we assume that the objective function g(x) goes to zero, since our system is underdetermined. The optimization step is then calculated based on the linearization around x. Therefore, the derivation of the method is different to what I did above in my question. Do you think I could also similarly derive this form from Newton's method?

Comment: What I still don't quite understand is the decomposition into Delta_x=y+z. Could you point me to a textbook or web article where I can read more about this?

Comment: @ubongoUga  Yes, this is the critical point The key word is orthogonal complement. Your favorite linear algebra textbook will discuss it. Any vector can be split into two components, one is our vector space of choice and the other is in the orthogonal complement of the vector space.

Comment: Cool. Thank you again for your help, this was really helpful.

Comment: @ubongoUga The two cases of $m < n$ and $m > n$ are really quite similar. I think that it would be worth you time to have a second look at $g(x) + Dg(x) \Delta x = 0$. Suppose that $Dg(x)$ is a *tall* matrix of full rank. Then this equation implies $Dg(x)^T g(x) + Dg(x)^T Dg(x) \Delta x = 0$ and we can solve for $\Delta x$. What we get is the least squares solution of the original overdetermined linear system. What I did above was to find the solution of the smallest 2-norm of an underdetermined system.

Comment: @ubongoUga  It might also be helpful to ignore the specific expressions for the Hessian and the Jacobian that is being used for the Gauss-Newton algorithm and just look for zeros of a function vector $g$ of several variables.

Comment: Thanks for the additional comments. It is much more clear now.